# embedding a call to a stored procedure with in a transaction that contains dynamic sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to call a stored procedure at the end of the insert-select statement 
but before the commit or rollback of the transaction, and I want the stored procedure to be a part of the transaction containing the insert-select. Is writing dynamic SQL the only option if I want the new code to be a part of the containing transaction?

The number of string appends is actually quite large (thousands) but I have only shared a small snippet of the code to highlight the concept and show what I want to do.

```
sqlStr.Append("BEGIN TRANSACTION; ")

sqlStr.Append("INSERT INTO table_chg (Column1, Column2) ")                                             
sqlStr.Append("SELECT r.Column8 , r.Column9 ")
sqlStr.Append("FROM v_table r, table1 r ")
sqlStr.Append("WHERE r.columnName1 = '{1}' ")
sqlStr.Append("  AND r.columnName2 = '{2}'; ")
sqlStr.Append(" ") 

/** ADD STORED PROCEDURE HERE    */

EXEC sp_storedProc '{1}'   **THIS DOES NOT WORK. BUT {1} does resolve to the correct variable that I need. Also the stored procedure works standalone and the VB.Net code does try to reference the stored procedure because if I give the stored procedure an incorrect name, I get an error back which says "stored procedure not found**

sqlStr.Append("IF @@ERROR <> 0 ")
sqlStr.Append("    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ")
sqlStr.Append("ELSE ")
sqlStr.Append("    COMMIT TRANSACTION; ")

strError = DatabaseClass.ExecuteNonQueryReturnError (String.Format(sqlStr.ToString(), parameter1, parameter2))
```

Comment: Any ideas about feasibility?

Comment: I assume that this is a by-product of the simplification you did to produce an example, but you're using the alias 'r' for both 'v_table' and 'table1'.  That will cause an error.

Comment: yes, that's correct. it was actually a huge sql statement that i cut down.....good observation...

Answer (score 1):

1. `@@ERROR` function is reset to null as soon as any other statement is executed after the error has occurred, so it's best to use a variable where you think an error may occur.
2. In your join condition you have used same alias `r` for both tables, this will cause an error. Aliases should be different.
3. Use `ON` clause in your join

For your `@@ERROR` function statement should look something like

**@@ERROR**

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DECLARE @Error INT;

    INSERT INTO table_chg (Column1, Column2)                                             
    SELECT r.Column8 , r.Column9 
    FROM v_table r1 INNER JOIN table1 r2          --<-- Alias should be different for 
    ON r1.ReferencingColumn = r2.ReferencingColumn     -- for both tables
    WHERE r1.columnName1  = 1         --<-- Use r1 or r2 alias here
     AND  r2.columnName2 = 2

  SET   @Error = @@ERROR;

IF (@Error <> 0) 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
ELSE 
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Try..Catch Blocks**

I would suggest you to use `try catch` block, something like this, which allows you to use the error function in catch block and access detailed information about the error.

```sql
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION
     DECLARE @Error INT;

        INSERT INTO table_chg (Column1, Column2)                                             
        SELECT r.Column8 , r.Column9 
        FROM v_table r1 INNER JOIN table1 r2          --<-- Alias should be different for 
        ON r1.ReferencingColumn = r2.ReferencingColumn     -- for both tables
        WHERE r1.columnName1  = 1         --<-- Use r1 or r2 alias here
         AND  r2.columnName2 = 2

  COMMIT TRANSACTION  

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

      SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRORNUMBER,
             ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMESSAGE
             .
             ...... (All the other error functions)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

1 - Create Transaction object and use `Try-block`

2 - Using your transaction object, execute `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` (insert) - It will return number of records affected.

3 - Using your transaction object, execute `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` (Strored procedure) - It will return number of records affected and [if you need] output parameters.

4 - Rollback or commit your transaction object based on results of  step #2 ans #3

5 - Don't do this

```
sqlStr.Append("INSERT INTO table_chg (Column1, Column2) ")                                               
sqlStr.Append("SELECT r.Column8 , r.Column9 ").....
```

Instead do this:

```
Dim sql as String = _
    "INSERT INTO table_chg (Column1, Column2) " & _
    "SELECT r.Column8 , r.Column9 ".......
```

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for #5?  Although the original poster doesn't say so, it looks as if he or she is using a `StringBuilder`.  What's the advantage to using a concatenated string instead?

Comment: String builder is absolute must when dealing with loops. But when the string is known beforehand it is better to declare a string. String builder takes resources. If you don't initialize it, it will resize itself as you add data, which will take even more resources. In the current situation, using `string` is more appropriate. String is array of bytes, and string builder is the mechanism to manage it. Here we don't need it.

Comment: You are correct. We should not be using a string builder. But unfortunately, I am stuck with this code base, and all that this code does is Stringbuilding with Sql Code.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TransactionScope

```
Using scope As TransactionScope = New TransactionScope
Try
'Here will be the DB call code
'Make some verifications if everyting was ok in DB
SCope.Complete()

Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Using
```

I will not use BEGIN TRY END TRY from SQL because is not catching all the time if an error has occured. For example if you called a method throw a linked server and an error has occured on linked server the begin try end try will not catch the error: Also "A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors that have a severity higher than 10 that do not close the database connection."

You can remove the TRANSACTION from SQL if you use TRANSACTIONSCOPE. If the scope.Complete() was not call because an error or validation after script execution, everything will be rollback.